# Java implementation of trace-on-error logging

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

[This blog post](http://henrikwarne.com/2014/01/21/session-based-logging/) describes an interesting approach to logging:

> When activated, if an exception (e.g. a NullPointerException) is thrown, the complete trace of the session up to that point is output, in addition to the stack trace. It works by starting session logging for every session, but only outputting the result if an exception occurs.

Is there an implementation of it in any Java logging framework?

Comment: I think that the way you need to think about it is in terms of storage. The trace log has to be stored per "session" ("session" needs to be defined by you), and then deleted if the session completes without an exception. The trace log has to be stored somehow regardless of whether an exception occurs or not. So the log must be "output" to somewhere, but it could be just somewhere in memory or a temporary file.

Comment: Yes, reasonably it would be buffered in memory.

Comment: The application I am working on at my work right now produces gigabytes of log. It wouldn't be safe to rely on memory for that, but it would depend on the case at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but it's quite possible to write a custom appender that delegates to the respective session log. For Logback, this could be something like:

```
class SessionLogAppender implements Appender<ILogEvent> {
    private static final TheadLocal<Object> sessionHolder = new ThreadLocal<Object>();

    private Map<Object, SessionLog> sessionLogs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    /** must be invoked when a new session begins */
    public static void begin(Object session) {
        sessionHolder.set(session);
    }

    /** must be invoked when a session ends */
    public static void end() {
        Object session = sessionHolder.get();
        writeIfNecessary(sessionLogs.get(session));
        sessionLogs.remove(session);

        sessionHolder.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void doAppend(ILogEvent e) {
        Object session = sessionHolder.get();
        SessionLog l = sessionLogs.get(session);
        if (l == null) {
            l = new SessionLog();
            sessionLogs.put(session, l);
        }
        l.append(e);
    }
}
```

This assumes that each session is handled by a dedicated thread.